# Sudden Problems With Dynamic Not Working On (Only) My Machine

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

My basic setup is this:

```
//caller
dynamic thingThatEndsUpBeingAJObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await httpClientResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
var parsedThing = Parse(thingThatEndsUpBeingAJObject);

//elsewhere...
private async Task<ParsedThing> Parse(dynamic json)
{
    dynamic referenceToThingIWant = json.ThingIWant;
    return new ParsedThing{ SomeProp = referenceToThingIWant; }
}
```

...where I end up getting a RuntimeBinderException on the reference to json.ThingIWant.

Oddly, if I put a watch on:

```
((JObject)json)["ThingIWant"]
```

I can see darn well that it's there!

Even more perplexing is that the code runs fine on everyone else's machine (and I believe it ran fine on mine till days ago)!

What on earth could cause such a strange quirk?!?

I've gone as far as restarting the computer, FWIW.

Specific error/stack trace is:

```
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'ThingIWant'
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderController.SubmitError(CError pError)
```

Comment: Can you post a stack trace?

Comment: @jdphenix Sure, but it's pretty short.

Comment: Have you made changes to the model that would affect "ThingIWant" ? Like, did "ParsedThing" change structure?

Comment: `var parsedThing = Parse(thingThatEndsUpBeingAJObject);` should be `var parsedThing = await Parse(thingThatEndsUpBeingAJObject);`, otherwise you may get odd results.

Comment: @RonBeyer - it didn't end up making a difference. :-(

Comment: If it is "only on my computer" I would guess there is something wrong with the Computer. Damage on the .NET installation is possible. Could also be 3rd party Interference: There used to be a case when some Virus Scanner interfered with the WindowsForms.dll, resulting in whole bunches of Programms suddenly running into AccessViolation exceptions all over the place.

Comment: What does the class definition for `ParsedThing` look like?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur - There is none; it's dynamic. The JSON could be { "ThingIWant": "Vacation" }.